# Mongoose automatically converting Binary data to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im experiencing some weird behaviour from Mongoose/MongoDB.

**My data schema is:**

```
    photo: {data: Buffer, contentType: String}
```

**I uploaded an image to mongoose using the following the code:**

```
let upload = (req, res) => {
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { photo: fs.readFileSync(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`)
  }, {safe: true, new: true})
    .exec()
    .then(() => {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {"message": "photo uploaded"})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)
    })
 };
```

**The above successfully uploads an image as follows:**

[image]

**The weird behaviour:**

According to my knowledge mongoose/mongoDB returned `binary data` as `binary data` and the user had to convert it to `base64 string` before it could be used. Am I wrong?

In my case when I pull the data from mongoose I don't get the `binary data`. I get the converted `base64`. **Please note that I have not placed any code anywhere that is converting binary data.**

Below is an image of what the returned data looks like:

[image]

**Before returning the data to the user I `console.log` my data server side:**

[image]

**My Questions:**

1. Can anyone explain whats causing this?
2. Is mongoose capable of automatically converting binary data?
3. Does this mean I don't need to implement "binary to base64" conversion code?

If mongoose is capable of automatically doing this then that is great! But I am confused whether this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: I think it's better to ask such question on Mongoose Github issue's tracker